# Publisher-Subscriber setup with WatchService

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to setup a 2 way publisher-subscriber using the WatchService in NIO.

I'm not terribly experienced with threads, so if I'm not making any sense feel free to call me out on it!

This is only a sample to figure out how the library works, but the production code is going to listen for a change in an input file, and when the file changes it will do some calculations and then write to an output file. This output file will be read by another program, some calculations will be run on it. The input file will then be written to and the cycle continues.

For this test though, I am making 2 threads with watchers, the first thread listens on `first.txt` and writes to `second.txt`, and the second thread waits on `second.txt` and writes to `first.txt`. All that I am doing is incrementing a count variable and writing to each thread's output file. Both of the threads have blocking calls and filters on what files they actually care about, so I figured the behavior would look like

Both threads are waiting on take() call.
Change `first.txt` to start the process
This triggers the first thread to change `second.txt` 
Which then triggers the second thread to change `first.txt` 
and so on.

Or so I hoped. The end result is that the threads get way out of sync and when I do this for count up to 1000, one thread is usually behind by more than 50 points.

Here is the code for the watcher

```
Watcher(Path input, Path output) throws IOException {
    this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    this.input = input;
    this.output = output;
    dir = input.getParent();
    dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
}

void watchAndRespond() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    while (count < 1000) {

        WatchKey key = watcher.take();

        for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
            if (! event.context().equals(input.getFileName())) {
                continue;
            }

            WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
            if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
                continue;
            }

            count++;

            try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output.toFile()))) {
                out.write(count + "");
            }
        }
        key.reset();
    }
}
```

I don't want to have to read the file to decide whether or not the file has changed, because these files in production could potentially be large.

I feel like maybe it is too complicated and I'm trying to deal with a scraped knee with amputation. Am I using this library incorrectly? Am I using the wrong tool for this job, and if so are there any other file listening libraries that I can use so I don't have to do polling for last edited?

EDIT:
Oops, here is the test I wrote that sets up the two threads

```
@Test
public void when_two_watchers_run_together_they_end_up_with_same_number_of_evaluation() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    //setup
    Path input = environment.loadResourceAt("input.txt").asPath();
    Path output = environment.loadResourceAt("output.txt").asPath();

    if (Files.exists(input)) {
        Files.delete(input);
    }
    if (Files.exists(output)) {
        Files.delete(output);
    }

    Thread thread1 = makeThread(input, output, "watching input");
    Thread thread2 = makeThread(output, input, "watching output");

    //act
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();

    Thread.sleep(50);

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(input.toFile()));
    out.write(0 + "");
    out.close();

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();

    int inputResult = Integer.parseInt(Files.readAllLines(input).get(0));
    int outputResult = Integer.parseInt(Files.readAllLines(output).get(0));
    //assert
    assertThat(inputResult).describedAs("Expected is output file, Actual is input file").isEqualTo(outputResult);
}

public Thread makeThread(Path input, Path output, String threadName) {
    return new Thread(() ->
    {
        try {
            new Watcher(input, output).watchAndRespond();
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            fail();
        }

    }, threadName);
}
```

I think the problem is that some of the modifications are putting multiple events into the queue and at this point I have no way to discern whether or not they are 2 events that were created by one save or 2 separate saves.

Answer (score 0):

The tool seems to be quite right but your code will have to be flow in sequence else everything is going to be out of sync as you have noticed.
Look at it as a transaction which has to be completed before another transaction starts.
In this case the transaction can boil down to 
1.) Detect File1 change 
2.) Modify File2
3.) Detect File2 change
4.) Modify File1

So before this cycle ends completely if another cycle starts then there will be trouble. When you are using Threads, the scheduling and execution is not entirely predictable so you would not know what your 2 threads are doing.
Whether they are doing things sequentially as per your requirements.
So you would have to share your Thread code for anyone to give a specific
solution.

Another point is can you keep a small change file which contains the change
and use that instead of using the bigger production file. That
way you can reduce the focus to a smaller object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something more specific I noticed after running your code.
Its quite fine...some points though...there is no need for
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
Both the threads are required to run concurrently so join is not 
needed.
For your main question ...the threads are out of sync because they
are connected to their own watcher objects and so the count value
is different for both the threads.
So depending on how the scheduler runs the threads...one of them
will get more mileage and will reach count 1000 first while the
other is still lagging behind.

I am editing in response to your comment....Take is a blocking call and
it is working perfectly. In my case the only event trapped is ENTRY_MODIFY
so no multiple event issue.
One tip is you can set dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_MODIFY); in code
to check only for modify events. Please see my code below..also
my printlns may help to get better understanding of the code flow.

public class WatcherTest {

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    Path input =  FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("txt", "input.txt");
    Path output =  FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("txt", "output.txt");

    if (Files.exists(input)) {
        Files.delete(input);
    }
    if (Files.exists(output)) {
        Files.delete(output);
    }

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new WatchFileTask(input, output ), "ThreadToOpt");
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new WatchFileTask(output, input ), "ThreadToInpt");

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();

    Thread.sleep(100);

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(input.toFile()));
    out.write(0 + "");
    out.close();

    //thread1.join();
    //thread2.join();

    //int inputResult = Integer.parseInt(Files.readAllLines(input, Charset.defaultCharset()).get(0));
    // int outputResult = Integer.parseInt(Files.readAllLines(output, Charset.defaultCharset()).get(0));

}
```

}

class FileWatcherService {

```
private WatchService watcher;
private Path input;
private Path output;
private Path dir;

private   int count = 0;

FileWatcherService(Path input, Path output) throws IOException {
    this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    this.input = input;
    this.output = output;
    Path dir = input.getParent();
    dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_MODIFY);
}


void watchAndRespond() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    while (count < 1000) {


        System.out.println("\n COUNT IS " + count + " in Thread " +  Thread.currentThread().getName());

        System.out.println("\n Blocking on Take in Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        WatchKey key = watcher.take();

        System.out.println("\n Out of Blocking State " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        int eventsPassed = 0;
        for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {

            if (!event.context().equals(input.getFileName())) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("\n File Context : " + event.context() + " Event Kind " + event.kind() + " in Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();


            if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
                continue;
            }

            eventsPassed++;
            count++;
            //synchronized(output){

                try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output.toFile()))) {
                    out.write(count + "");
                    System.out.println("\n Wrote count : " +  count + " to File " + output.getFileName() + " in Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
        //  }
        }
        System.out.println("\n The eventsPassed counter is " + eventsPassed + " \n for thread  " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        key.reset();
    }
```

}
}

Comment: But I thought that take() was a blocking call. Between take() and the filter under the for loop it shouldn't be able to get ahead at all if there is one event for the write. On that note, sometimes the write triggers multiple events. Only sometimes. Annoying.